# Why are my angular material form inputs not showing up correctly only in one component?

Tags: angular, material-design

I'm developing a web application and all of a sudden the form material inputs stopped rendering correctly in one component only:

[image: components aren't showing up correctly]

Here's how they look in other components (expected and correct output):

[image: how material inputs look in other components]

Sample code for output above:
Wrong output (the first image):

```
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Oggetto</mat-label>
            <input matInput placeholder="Oggetto" formControlName="oggetto">
        </mat-form-field>
```

sample code for second image(works well):

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Nome</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Nome" formControlName="name">
  </mat-form-field>
```

Note that the console doesn't show any errors.
Happy to give more context if needed

Comment: do u have "import hammerjs"; in pollyfills.ts file? If not, add this line and run "npm i hammerjs"

Comment: can you disclose, what error you are getting.

Comment: I installed the hammerjs and added it to polyfills.
The warning about not having hammerjs went away, but the problem is not solved.

I'm not getting any errors or warnings in the console.

Comment: do u have "@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';" or any theme like this in styles.scss?  if not, add this line also, somtimes this also might be the reason

Comment: Yes i have @import '../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
Remember that material is working in all components but one, so the problem must be local to that component I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer: I was trying to set
 `overflow:hidden` on the html tag and accidentally set

```
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
```

on the component.
I removed that line and now it's working again.